# Is $\overline{T(\overline{B_X})} = \overline{T(B_X)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a continuous linear functional from Banach space $X$ to Banach space $Y$. Is it true that  $\overline{T(\overline{B_X})} = \overline{T(B_X)}$? Here $B_X$ denotes the open unit ball of $X$, and the overline denote the closure operation (in respective strong topologies).

It seems obviously true by a diagonal argument, but I need a rigorous proof.

Comment: Where did you find this question? Perhaps you could try rigorising the argument you already had, or at least state your diagonal argument? Typically, questions require more context or effort shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If $x_n \in \overline{B_X}$, $y_n = (1 - 1/n) x_n \in B_X$, and $\|T(x_n) - T(y_n)\| \to 0$, so if $z = \lim_{n \to \infty} T(x_n)$ then $z = \lim_{n \to \infty} T(y_n)$.

Comment: The proof is shorter than the one I had. Since the map is from $X$ to $Y$, it's probably better to denote $y_n$ by $x_n'$, and denote $z$ by $y$. Then it would be perfect since $y\in Y$, and $x_n' \in X$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is true in a general context. Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a function. Then, $f$ is continuous if and only if $$\forall A\subseteq X  \hspace{15mm}  f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$$ Thus, if $f$ is continuous, then for any $A\subseteq X$ we have $\overline{f(\overline{A})}\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$. Also, by the properties of images and closures: $$f(A)\subseteq f(\overline{A}) \Rightarrow \overline{f(A)} \subseteq\overline{f(\overline{A})}.$$ We get $\overline{f(A)}=\overline{f(\overline{A})}$ for all $A\subseteq X $.